# How to create logger's zip file of last 5 days in spring boot using log4j?

Tags: java

I follow this example but this example use xml file.
I want to use properties file.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-rollingfileappender-example/

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link on how it can be configured using different options like YAML/JSON/Properties

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

specific to properties:

https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/